# WKWebView not play webM audio file

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I have application who is loading some web page.
Creating webView :

```
    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
 
    config.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = .all

    webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
    webView.isInspectable = true

    let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "example.com")

    webView.load(request)
```

in this page i have audio file on different format (mp3/mp4/webM). I can play mp3 and mp4 format all is correct but for webM i getting error.

In my webView look like : mp3/mp4 file.

[image: mp3/mp4 file]

In my webView look like : webM.

[image: webM file]

I printed the error in the console but nothing useful.
[image: Console error]

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @tomerpacific  i upload image with error but I don't see anything interesting.

Comment: Looks like there is no support for WebM in iOS [Reference](https://www.quora.com/Why-doesnt-WebM-work-on-iOS)